# Twitter API: is it possible to get number of retweets and number of media images?

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping

Is it possible through the Twitter API to get the *total* number of retweets a user has? Not just on a specific post, but the total number of retweets associated with a specific account? Or alternatively, what fraction of all tweets were retweeted content rather than original posts?

Also, is it possible to get the number of media images associated with an an account? What I mean is, if you go to a user's page, on the lefthand side it will say something like "2,200 Photos and Videos". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not using the official API, no.

The [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show) shows only the following "counts"

- followers_count
- friends_count
- listed_count
- favourites_count
- statuses_count

If you want the number of media, you can scrape the HTML from the user's Twitter page.  Look for the class `PhotoRail-headingWithCount`

I've not seen anything which shows how many times a user has been retweeted. Where do you see that value?

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can. From Twitter [REST APIs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public): [GET statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline):

There is a parameter called `include_rts`:

> When set to false , the timeline will strip any native retweets (though they will still count toward both the maximal length of the timeline and the slice selected by the count parameter). Note: If you’re using the trim_user parameter in conjunction with include_rts, the retweets will still contain a full user object.

So if you want to get count of all retweets you need to set that value to `true` count all entities and then set it to `false` and then subtract those values and then you get number of *retweets*.

**NOTE**: Also set `trim_user` to `true` to get less data(omitting user info of each tweet)

If you want to get count of media, then you need to count all `media` entities in those tweets: [Entities in Objects](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/entities-in-twitter-objects). To separate them by type, you need to look at the `type` attribute of each element of `media` attribute.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to *see* retweets. They want the *number* of retweets.

Comment: @TerenceEden first of all, OP wanted problem to be solved, without any approach. And secondly, what is the problem to count retweets from the response? I mentioned that OP need to do so.

Comment: "the total number of retweets associated with a specific account" there's no way to get that just from calling the timeline twice - unless the user has a very low number of Tweets.

Comment: @TerenceEden very low is 3200?